# Showing larger images with AddThis widget

Tags: javascript, social-networking, addthis

I'm using the AddThis widget and I copied the default code for the first option they have, which is the one with the facebook like, tweet etc... that code being:

```
<!-- AddThis Button BEGIN -->
<div class="addthis_toolbox addthis_default_style ">
    <a class="addthis_button_facebook_like" fb:like:layout="button_count"></a>
    <a class="addthis_button_tweet"></a>
    <a class="addthis_button_pinterest_pinit"></a>
    <a class="addthis_counter addthis_pill_style"></a>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">var addthis_config = {"data_track_addressbar":true};</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#pubid=ra-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"></script>
<!-- AddThis Button END -->
```

However I wanted to add a Google Plus button as well, so I added this in to the code:

```
<a class="addthis_button_google_plusone"></a>
```

However this output a much smaller image compared to the others. Is there any way to get the more appropriate sized image?

Here is what it currently looks like:

[image]

As you can see the Google Plus icon is too small, however that's the right icon I want, just bigger; don't want the "badge".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**:

Use `size` to size your buttons:

```
<a class="addthis_button_google_plusone" g:plusone:size="medium"></a>
```

[Link to guide](http://support.addthis.com/customer/portal/articles/381237-third-party-buttons#google-plus1) *- Larger Standard*

---

**[Add this third party buttons - link](http://support.addthis.com/customer/portal/articles/381237-third-party-buttons#google-plus-badge)** (like Google +1)

Also, Code (maybe this is what you want):

```
<div class="addthis_toolbox addthis_default_style">
     <a class="addthis_button_google_plusone_badge" g:plusone:href="...your-link..."></a>
</div>
```

**OR**, in your code itself, just add another anchor tag to the div:

```
<a class="addthis_button_google_plusone_badge" ></a>
```

Comment: Thanks, but didn't want the "bade" icon. I have updated my post to elaborate more. :)

Comment: @Brett, Updated answer. Check the link also to see more configs